# HTML Canvas print preview

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to print canvas content. I have following javascript code on the print button click to get a print preview.

```
     function openPrintDialog(isLandscape, paperSize) {
            /*jshint multistr: true */
            var style = '<style context="program"> \
            @media print { \
                * { \
                    display: block; \
                } \
\
                html, body, .hidden-print-image, *{ \
                    display: block; \
                    text-align: center; \
                } \
\
                img { \
                    ' + (isLandscape ? 'max-width: ' + paperSize.heightMm + ';' : 'max-width: ' + paperSize.widthMm + ';') + '\
                    ' + (isLandscape ? 'max-height:' + paperSize.widthMm + ';' : 'max-height: ' + paperSize.heightMm + ';') + '\
                } \
            } \
            </style>';

            $('head').append(style);            
            window.print();

            $timeout(function() {
                $('[context=program]').remove();

                $('.hidden-print-image').remove();
            }, 2000);
        }
```

This is my canvas content including the page content.

[image]

I only want to export and print the image only. Don't want to show or print the page content.

At the moment I see all elements on the print preview. How can I exclude all the elements except for the image?

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't that css rule for * be display: none ? Followed by making the single element you ARE interested in, display as a block?

Comment: @enhzflep I tried setting the * to display:none then it doesn't display anything at all. Just shows a blank screen. My issues is, how do I find the correct element tag on canvas to set the display property? I tried setting img { display: block; } but no luck

Answer (score 0):

```
printJS({
  printable: ['images/print-01-highres.jpg'],
  type: 'image',
  imageStyle: 'width:50%;margin-bottom:20px;'
 });
```

From [this library](https://printjs.crabbly.com/), which has a function that is essential for what you are looking.